# Difference between Palankarta and Palanhaara

Tags: vishnu, shiva, terminology

We all are aware of the fact that Lord Vishnu is Palankarta because he takes care of all the lokas like a mother and protects them like a father. He plays Father and Mother role for all lokas. He is palaka of all lokas same as parents is palaka of their child, that's why he is known as Palankarta.

But I am confused with the word Palanhar, which is mostly used for Lord Shiva. I have seen this word is being used for Lord Shiva a lot. Palanhaara word sounds similar to Palankarta, So this means Shiva's work is similar to Vishnu, but I know Shiva is Lord of Destruction. He is destroyer, then why palanhaara word is used for Shiva.

What is exact meaning of word palanhaar and why this word is used for Lord Shiva and what is the difference between both words? What our scriptures says about this?

Comment: Hara may be the Hindi suffix rather than Sanskrit.

Comment: @Pandya Okay, may be both Palanhar and Palankarta are hindi words. But still if we knows who is Palankarta and why he called palankarta then there shud also be some info regarding Palanhar like: who and why he is Palanhar. If Scriptures only talks in Sanskrit and they can't describe the meaning of this word then any other source from hinduism which can describe the relation of this (Palanhar) word with Shiva are also welcome.